# When can one break the rule of using "does" instead of "do"?

Tags: verb-agreement

> Listen, Walter, because you shot Jesse James **don't** make you Jesse James. — Breaking Bad

Why is it *don't* and not *doesn't*?

Comment: In some very informal varieties of English, "don't" is used instead of "doesn't". Another way to say this is that you  shouldn't use "don't" instead of "doesn't" except in the most restricted circumstances (which probably means 'never' if you're  new to English. Which dialects exactly? AAVE, Southern, uh.. rural... uh... urban too? Another common informal version is "du?n't" which is a slurred version of "doesn't".

Comment: @FumbleFingers That question doesn't ask the same thing. It asks "Which is correct?" and this asks "When can one use one instead of the other?" (also, the answers to the other don't come close to answering this one even if they are the same question)

Comment: @Mitch: It was also closed as Off Topic, presumably because those who closevoted considered it too basic for ELU. That's certainly what I think about this question.

Comment: Because bad guys who cook ain't grammatical.

Comment: It's perfectly grammatical, just not Standard English. See the many examples in the linked question, and the questions linked in turn from there. It is ubiquitous. It is not an error, not a one-off slip of the tongue. In fact in some dialects or registers it is the only correct form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they are writing speech in a show with incorrect grammar [on purpose].

Comment: The grammar is not incorrect in the dialect used. The reassignment of the marker that in Standard English means "third person singular present tense" is characteristic of Celtic-influenced dialects, such as Hiberno-English, the Newfoundland dialect, African American Vernacular English, and much of the vernacular on the ground in the southeastern United States. The idea that there is one and only one "true" English with a single grammar is utter nonsense.

Comment: In those dialects, *does* (or *doesn't*) would always represent the habitual, regardless of person.